How can I Vectorize the DotProduct calculation of 2 arrays?
I have the following method which calcualtes the dot product of the given arrays:
static double DotProduct(uint[] vecA, uint[] vecB)
{
    double dotProduct = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < vecA.Length; i++)
    {
        dotProduct += (vecA[i] * vecB[i]);
    }
    return dotProduct;
}

I want to improve upon this and utilize SIMD and AVX. My attempt of vectorizing this as follows throws an ArgumentOutOfRange exception:
static double DotProduct(uint[] vecA, uint[] vecB)
{
    Vector<uint> vec1 = new Vector<uint>(vecA);
    Vector<uint> vec2 = new Vector<uint>(vecB);

    return Vector.Dot(vec1, vec2);
}

What am I missing?

That vector code only works if your arrays are exactly the length of a vector. If they're short arrays (shorter than a vector, hence the exception), that's not a good situation for SIMD anyway. If you're sometimes dealing with short arrays and sometimes bigger arrays then it's still useful to do this.

You gonna need much more code to vectorize that function. Here’s one possible implementation, which requires FMA3 runtime support.
/// <summary>Assuming the numbers don't exceed int.MaxValue, convert uint vector to FP64</summary>
[MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
static unsafe Vector256<double> upcast( Vector128<int> iv )
{
#if DEBUG
    Debug.Assert( Sse41.TestZ( iv, Vector128.Create( unchecked((int)0x80000000) ) ) );
#endif
    return Avx.ConvertToVector256Double( iv );
}

/// <summary>Load 4 uint numbers and upcast to FP64</summary>
[MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
static unsafe Vector256<double> load4( uint* rsi ) =>
    upcast( Vector128.Load( (int*)rsi ) );

/// <summary>Make permutation vector for <c>vpshufb</c> to load remainder from the arrays</summary>
[MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
static unsafe Vector128<byte> makeRemainderPermute( int maskLength )
{
    Debug.Assert( maskLength >= 0 && maskLength < 4 );

    // https://vcsjones.dev/csharp-readonly-span-bytes-static/
    const byte n = 0x80;
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> remainderShuffleBuffer =
    [
        // Identity shuffle i.e. [a,b,c,d] -> [a,b,c,d]
        0,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7, 8,9,10,11, 12,13,14,15,
        // [a,b,c,d] -> [ b, c, d, 0 ]
        4,5,6,7, 8,9,10,11, 12,13,14,15, n,n,n,n,
        // [a,b,c,d] -> [ c, d, 0, 0 ]
        8,9,10,11, 12,13,14,15, n,n,n,n, n,n,n,n,
        // [a,b,c,d] -> [ d, 0, 0, 0 ]
        12,13,14,15, n,n,n,n, n,n,n,n, n,n,n,n,
    ];

    fixed( byte* rsi = remainderShuffleBuffer )
        return Vector128.Load( rsi + maskLength * 16 );
}

/// <summary>Same as <see cref="load4"/>, apply permutation on the bytes before upcasting to FP64</summary>
[MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
static unsafe Vector256<double> load4Rem( uint* rsi, Vector128<byte> perm )
{
    Vector128<byte> bytes = Vector128.Load( (byte*)rsi );
    Vector128<int> iv = Ssse3.Shuffle( bytes, perm ).As<byte, int>();
    return upcast( iv );
}

/// <summary>Horizontal sum of FP64 AVX vector</summary>
[MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
static double hadd( Vector256<double> v )
{
    Vector128<double> v2 = Sse2.Add( v.GetUpper(), v.GetLower() );
    return Sse2.UnpackHigh( v2, v2 ).ToScalar() + v2.ToScalar();
}

/// <summary>Compute dot product of two vectors in FP64 precision</summary>
[MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization )]
public static double dot( uint[] vecA, uint[] vecB )
{
    int length = vecA.Length;
    if( length != vecB.Length )
        throw new ArgumentException();

    if( length >= 4 && Fma.IsSupported )
    {
        Vector256<double> acc = Vector256<double>.Zero;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed( uint* aFixt = vecA )
            fixed( uint* bFixt = vecB )
            {
                uint* pa = aFixt;
                uint* pb = bFixt;
                uint* aLast = pa + ( length - 4 );
                uint* bLast = pb + ( length - 4 );

                for( ; pa < aLast; pa += 4, pb += 4 )
                {
                    Vector256<double> a = load4( pa );
                    Vector256<double> b = load4( pb );
                    acc = Fma.MultiplyAdd( a, b, acc );
                }

                // Handle the remainder
                {
                    Vector128<byte> perm = makeRemainderPermute( unchecked((int)( pa - aLast )) );
                    Vector256<double> a = load4Rem( aLast, perm );
                    Vector256<double> b = load4Rem( bLast, perm );
                    acc = Fma.MultiplyAdd( a, b, acc );
                }
            }
            return hadd( acc );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        double dotProduct = 0;
        for( var i = 0; i < length; i++ )
            dotProduct += ( vecA[ i ] * vecB[ i ] );
        return dotProduct;
    }
}

It is possible to improve performance further by using multiple accumulators. See that answer for an example of that for FP32 dot product function in C++.

My CPU does not support AVX or FMA3 but it does support SSE. I can see you are falling back to a normal loop in case of FMA3 not being supported. How can this be improved to first fallback to SSE then normal loop?

@MaYaN That’s surprising, that tech is 10 years old by now. The newest mainstream Intel CPUs without AVX1 is Westmere, these chips are from 2010. The newest mainstream Intel CPUs without FMA3 is Ivy Bridge from 2012, discontinued in 2015. Computers don’t usually live that long.
Anyway, without AVX1 or FMA you gonna need to make something substantially different. Use Sse2.Add( Sse2.Multiply( a, b ), c ) to emulate Fma.MultiplyAdd( a, b, c ), and note SSE vectors are twice as narrow i.e. only 16 bytes = two FP64 numbers per vector.

I know, I have a dual socket x5650. It's a long story but that's where I need to run these on. Thanks a lot for your help.
